# EF Core 6 generates foreign keys with temp_id{n}

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

Recently I recognized that EF Core 6 generates foreign keys with temp_id{n}.
P.S. I use Postgres with 'UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention'.

```
 migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "fk_something_temp_id1",
            table: "sometable",
            column: "someid",
            principalTable: "someothertable",
            principalColumn: "id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

It's happening when table contains two or more foreign keys. Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I haven't found a solution though as it seems to be a problem in the extension. I have created the issue in the project itself too: https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.NamingConventions/issues/198

Hopefully some great minded developers will help us out :)